# In PostgreSQL how do I generate a script that will recreate the database and all of its contents?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, postgresql-14

I'm trying to generate a SQL script that will recreate a Database I have on my installation of PostgreSQL but I have not been successful yet.

I'm able to create a backup file of my database using the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_dump" -U postgres -p 5432 -W -F p -h localhost TEST_DB > C:\Postgres_DB_Backups\TEST_DB.sql
```

When I open this file, which is a backup of my database, and try to run that file in pgAdmin, I get a "PostgreSQL restore error: "syntax error at or near "x"".

Not sure what's causing that error though because all I did was backup the database and make no other changes. I searched on stack overflow for similar issues and all I saw was something about it could be an encoding issue but it did not mention any way to address the issue if that is indeed the problem.

What exactly did I do wrong? What is the best way to backup a database in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use shell redirection on Windows with `pg_dump`. The shell will helpfully "correct" encoding issues and corrupt your dump. Instead, specify the output filename with the `-f` option:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_dump" -U postgres -p 5432 -W -F p -h localhost -f C:\Postgres_DB_Backups\TEST_DB.sql TEST_DB
```

To restore using `psql`, which also supports `-f`:

```
psql -U postgres -f C:\Postgres_DB_Backups\TEST_DB.sql TEST_DB_DB
```

A similar problem was seen in this question:
[issues with encoding and pg_dump/restore between windows and linux](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35112/issues-with-encoding-and-pg-dump-restore-between-windows-and-linux)

Comment: Should I change my restore commands as well? Or is what I have below ok? C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin> psql -U postgres TEST_DB_DB < C:\Postgres_DB_Backups\TEST_DB.sql

Comment: I added an example of `psql` usage to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A dump generated by `pg_dump` cannot be run as an SQL script in pgAdmin because of the way it mixes `COPY` statements and data. If you use the `--inserts` option of `pg_dump`, you might have more luck.